# SSL Self Signed Certificate and Lighttpd Webserver, data from multiple servers

Tags: ssl-certificate, lighttpd

I have migrated the lighttpd webserver on server (10.10.10.1)to run using HTTPs. I am able to get partial data using https if I accept the Security Certificate Warning which the browser gives as we use Self Signed Certificates.

My server (10.10.10.1) request data from 3 other servers there ip address are 10.10.10.2,10.10.10.3,10.10.10.4
If I access the webpage of the first server [10.10.10.1], I accept the certificate warning and webpage show me some partial data as my browser still doesn't trust other servers i.e. 10.10.10.2,10.10.10.3,10.10.10.4 and only the first request to 10.10.10.1 succeed and rest of the request shows security certificates errors:-

```
GET 200 html  https://10.10.10.1/www/camp/resources/camp_tree_status.php
GET ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_ERRORS https://10.10.10.2/www/camp/resources/camp_tree_status.php
GET ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_ERRORS https://10.10.10.3/www/camp/resources/camp_tree_status.php
GET ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_ERRORS https://10.10.10.4/www/camp/resources/camp_tree_status.php
```

**These logs are from httpwatch plugin.

Now If I access webpage for 10.10.10.2 and accepts the security warning, from the same browser session, i get:-

```
GET (Cache) html   https: //10.10.10.1 /www/campus/resources/camp_tree_status.php
GET 200 html       https: //10.10.10.2 /www/camp/resources/camp_tree_status.php
GET ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_ERRORS h ttps://10.10.10.3/www/camp/resources/camp_tree_status.php
GET ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_ERRORS h ttps://10.10.10.4/www/camp/resources/camp_tree_status.php
```

Meaning now my browser trust 10.10.10.1 and 10.10.10.2 and request to them are successful, although the data for 10.10.10.1 was cached.
If i continue like this i will get all the data for all the servers.

How can i make my browser to trust these servers so that all the request succeed upfront and i need not to manually access each server individually so that my browser can trust them?

I am creating my certificate as:-

```
$ openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 1825 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
...
..............
writing new private key to 'mycert.pem'

You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a  DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.

Country Name (2 letter code) [XX]:country
State or Province Name (full name) []:state
Locality Name (eg, city) [Default City]:mycity
Organization Name (eg, company) [Default Company Ltd]:mycompany
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:muunit
Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:myserver
Email Address []:
```

My lighttpd.conf file ssl configuration is:-

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "0.0.0.0:443" {
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.pemfile = "/etc/ mycert.pem"
}
```

I have tried few thing like:-

1. Using the IP address in the Common Name of certificate
2. Installing the Certificate in the browser upfront to Trusted Root certification Authorities store.
3. Adding all the server IP Addresses in the Trusted Site list of my browser

But wasn't able to find a solution to the above problem. Any ideas what can be done here?

Comment: I would create a CA (scripts are bundled with openssl) und sign the server certs with the CA cert, which is installed in the browsers. You can add as many servers and certs as you want.

Comment: Thanks sebix for your reply. Delete the post from serverfault. I kind of figure out the same yesterday to create a CA and sign the certs, but than i ran in to another issue which is how do i sign these certificates dynamically, the reason for this is that the ip address for these servers can be different for different deployments and I dont have any domain name for these servers which i can use in the Common Name. Do you have any further suggestion..Thanks

Comment: The webservers can use SNI (server name indication) to show the appropriate server cert, depending on what server name the client requested.